# Extra line feeds in IntelliJ Run toolbar in case TestNG execution

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I didn't find some options responsible for that in settings. If I execute some code bot as TestNG test case, it doesn't add any additional line feeds

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALkla.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow/comment the similar issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218927